# Builds of Android package fail with 'apply' message after updating SDK - how to fix?

Tags: android, ant, build-error

I recently upgraded the Android SDK on our build machine, and now Android builds using Ant fail with the obscure message:

```
The <apply> type doesn't support the nested "path" element.
```

Our build.xml is the standard one generated by Android tools, and we automatically run

```
android update project -p .
```

before Ant runs the debug task.
The error message appears during the `-dex` phase of the build process.

Since this buildfile is using one of the standard Android templates, I'm not sure what's causing this change in behavior.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I figured it out. Seems that Android version 8 or higher now **require** you to have ant 1.8 or higher (I was still using 1.6.5). The fix was simply to upgrade my ant installation to the latest version.